# Can a host launch a DOS attack on Ethernet?

Tags: ethernet

Here is my trail of thought:
Since Ethernet works on the principle of CSMA/CD one can possible setup a rogue host which transmits packets all the time forcing other to exponentially back off until they can no longer transmit any data. Now the InterFrameGap can allow opportunities for the rogue host to detect collision itself but lets say we make the rogue host adapter such that it does not back of exponentially and starts re-transmitting as soon as it detects a collision. Am I missing something here>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On older single collision domain networks, yes, this was called a "chattering" host or NIC and cause plenty of problems as the rest of the network had to deal with the limited bandwidth.

On modern switched networks this has much more limited effect, though it depends on the switches.

Comment: Why is this not a problem on a modern switched networks. Can you point to the right reference if this is too trivial to answer.

Comment: Because switches break up collision domains, since each port on a switch is a separate collision domain.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_bridge and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_avoidance

Comment: It's still potentially a problem for the chattering host; but the rest of the network is switched. A switched network limits collision domains to each link (eliminating them ideally). So if a NIC is chattering it may saturate it's individual link to the switch, but the switch will not repeat the chatter to the rest of the network.

Comment: What if the chattering host keeps sending broadcasts?

Comment: Then you could potentially saturate the receiving links, but you could not deny them the ability to transmit as well.  Particularly since switches are full-duplex.

Comment: This is unrelated but why is the IFG 96 bytes for ethernet?

Comment: Many higher-end switches will automatically start disallowing broadcasts from NICs that send "too many". Also, since there is no guarantee of delivery a good percentage of other traffic would "beat" the chattering to the ports and still get through.

Comment: @Bruce the IFG for sending is 96, but for receiving is 47 (for various reasons it's not terribly uncommon for it to be this short). Back in the day comms chips weren't nearly as precise as they are now, so they defined 47 bits of "silence" and 63 bits of alternating "preamble" so the cards could detect and calibrate themselves to the changing conditions of each new packet. I'm sure these number came from testing multiplied by a large safety factor.

Comment: What would happen with a NIC chattering to Ethernet broadcast with (not so smart) switches? Just curious, _many_ years ago one of our thinnet NICs went crazy and brought the whole department net down.

Comment: @vonbrand There's no such thing as 'not so smart' switches. In the day there were hubs and bridges, which had broadcast/collision domains similar to Thinnet and Thicknet. A NIC that chattered (continuously sent a signal, whether it was actual data or otherwise) would cause collisions in the collision domain (so nobody else could send during this time). It indeed creates a denial of service attack on the network. It's fairly rare to find networks with a single collision domain anymore, because the aforementioned problems, and the way GbE (and faster) works.